# C language: buffer size, why when input more than the buffer size still works?

Tags: c, buffer

Question: why when inputting more than 12 characters, the program below still works? Thanks.
Background: I am looking on an exercise which requires the function to read unlimited number of characters and print them,
I saw this solution (from one's gitbook)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#define BUF_SIZE 12

void good_echo(void) 
{
    char buf[BUF_SIZE];
    while(1) {
        /* function fgets is interesting */
        char* p = fgets(buf, BUF_SIZE, stdin);
        if (p == NULL) {
            break;
        }
        printf("%s", p);
    }
    return;
}

int main(void) 
{
    good_echo();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `fgets()` in this context reads up to 11 characters at a time (or up to and including the newline if there's a newline before the 11 characters are filled), adds a null byte, and returns.  Your printing code then prints the up-to-11 characters without adding a newline or anything.  Thus, all the data is read and echoed cleanly.

Change your `printf()` to `printf("[%s]\n", p);` and you'll see how it works more clearly.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. I suppose I understand better now.